# Override a node template suggestion with template in custom module

Tags: 8, theming

We have a content type that is added to the drupal system Programmatically when we install one of our custom modules. Essentially the module handle incoming property data from a 3rd party and creates a node entity for each property.

The content type created is named `properties` and as such its template suggestion shown in Twig debugging is `node--properties--full.html.twig`, see below:

[image]

I am creating a second custom module called `lrg_property_display` and my intention is that this module will handle all the rendering related functionality as I want to keep the API import related functionality separate from the rendering. My module structure is shown below:

[image]

I have created my module and followed a couple sites suggestions that I simply create a template file in my module and in the .module file implement the `HOOK_THEME` method, which I have done as shown:

```
function lrg_property_display_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    $theme['node__property_display__full'] = [
        'template' => 'node--property-display--full',
        'base hook' => 'node'
    ];

    return $theme;
}
```

Clearing cache and refreshing the page though is showing that the theme is not been applied.

Where am I going wrong with this please? I basically need the `node--property-display--full.html.twig` template within the module to be used whenever a node of the type `Properties` is viewed.

**UPDATE**

I added the following code to my theme file (Theme name is `white_label`) which seemed to produce an error which suggests it 'almost' works, albiet I'd prefer not having to do a suggestion in the theme but want it in the module. I can live with it though if this works for the short/medium term:

```
function white_label_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    return array(
        'node__properties__full' => array(
            'render element' => 'elements',
            'template' => 'node--property-display--full',
            'base hook' => 'node',
            'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'lrg_property_display') . '/templates',
        )
    );
}
```

This then looks for the template `node--property-display--full.html.twig` but its looking in the main theme directory not in the module, even with the path specification.

The error returned was:

```
he website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.Twig_Error_Loader: Template "themes/custom/white_label/templates/nodes/node--property-display--full.html.twig" is not defined.
```

Reference image for comment in @Leigh's answer

[image]

Comment: In the second example the name of the content type changed, is this correct?

Comment: It looks like you’re taking an incoming argument, modifying and returning it - does it need to be passed by reference? &$theme?

Comment: @4k4 Content type name is still the same and its suggestion is `node--properties--full.html.twig`. So when a viewer hits a node which is of type `properties` I want it to use my module template `node--property-display--full.html.twig` instead.

@Kevin I am unsure, the arguments for the theme hook suggest its not by reference, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.6.x

Comment: If the content type name is the same then use `node--properties--full.html.twig` in the module, too.

Comment: @4k4 - I tried that originally, doesn't get picked up.

Comment: if you work with `'node__property__full' => [
      'base hook' => 'node',
    ],`  template `node--property--full..html.twig` should work without `template` property, and  `'node__property__full' => [
      'base hook' => 'node',
      'template' => 'node--property-display--full'
    ],` should work with `node--property-display--full.html.twig` .

Comment: in your update just change `node__properties__full` by `node__property__full`  and remove `'render element'` and `'path'` keys no need to, and it will take your template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't your array key wrong? It should be:

```
 $theme['node__property__full'] = [
    'template' => 'node--property-display--full',
    'base hook' => 'node'
];
```

If you're wanting to target the "full" display and your content type has a machine name of "property"

I'm doing something similar targetting a node of type "news" and display node "teaser":

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
   'node__news__teaser' => [
      'template' => 'node--news--teaser',
      'base hook' => 'node'
    ],
  ];
}
```

And my folder structure is:

/modules/custom/mymodule/templates/node--news--teaser.html.twig

Comment: Just tried this and it ends up simply using the base `node.html.twig`

`* node--42--full.html.twig
   * node--42.html.twig
   * node--properties--full.html.twig
   * node--properties.html.twig
   * node--full.html.twig
   x node.html.twig`

Comment: And you've cleared the cache? As I'm doing essentially the same thing but with the "teaser" display mode and it's working fine

Comment: Yea I drush cr everytime. Could you show your folder structure for your test module etc so I can compare please? Its possible I have missed something quite small somewhere.

Comment: Yeah no problem ive just pasted in exactly what im doing. I think its similar to yours apart from the template file name but that can actually be whatever you want, you just have to specify it in the array in the 'template' key

Comment: I've done exactly like yours apart from the teaser mode and just doesnt want to work.

See last image in question for new structure that matches yours

Comment: I'm running out of ideas then! Your module is definitely enabled?

Comment: Yea - have even uninstalled/reinstalled and then drush cr'ed the lot. For now I am just going to use the template suggestion given by twig debugging. It means the template living outside of the module which I can deal with for the moment. Thanks for your help Leigh

Comment: Ah looking at this again it's because your content type actually has a machine name of "properties" does it? Not property! So you need to change the array key to node__properties__full to match the machine name

Comment: Yea tried that, no joy.

Comment: I just followed this answer to over-ride the template for my content type, and it worked perfectly.  Thank you @Leigh

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {

        $extension   = '.html.twig';
        $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE');
        $files       = file_scan_directory($module_path . '/templates', '/' . preg_quote($extension) . '$/');

        $fs = \Drupal::service('file_system');

        foreach ($files as $file) {
          $template = $fs->basename($file->filename, $extension);
          $theme    = str_replace('-', '_', $template);
          $__expt = explode('__', $theme, 2);
          $base_theme = empty($__expt[0]) ? null : $__expt[0];
          $specific = empty($__expt[1]) ? null : $__expt[1];
          if (!empty($specific) && isset($theme_registry[$base_theme])) {
            $theme_info = array(
              'template'   => $template,
              'path'       => $fs->dirname($file->uri),
              'render element'  => $theme_registry[$base_theme]['render element'],
              'base hook'  => $base_theme,
              'type'       => 'module',
              'theme path' => $module_path,
              'preprocess functions' => $theme_registry[$base_theme]['preprocess functions'],
            );

            $theme_registry[$theme] = $theme_info;
          }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the theme suggestion?

**MYMODULE.module**:

```
// This first function here.

/**
 ** Implements hook_theme_suggestions_hook().
 **/
function lrg_property_display_theme_suggestions_node(array $variables) {
  return [
    'node__properties'
  ];
}

/**
 ** Implements hook_theme().
 **/
function lrg_property_display_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'node__properties' => [
      'template' => 'node--properties',
      'base hook' => 'node',
    ],
  ];
}
```

You can also declare a specific template file:

```
function hook_theme_suggestions_hook(array $variables) {
  return [
    'my_very_specific_template'
  ];
}

function hook_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'my_very_specific_template' => [
      'base hook' => 'node',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this without any success, its rendering the node using the core node template

Comment: I would test without the `--full` part as suggested in the other answer. Disable the module, do you still see the theme suggestions in inspection? Maybe that content type suggestion is already loaded from your theme? Can you break the site with some gibberish in each of the above functions to ensure they are running? In a module, you need to load the theme files and add the theme suggestions.

Comment: XDebug didnt stop on breakpoints within both the functions, so can only assume the are not been called. Ill disable etc and see what happens.

Comment: Maybe need to double check folder names, file names, and function names, etc. for typos. If you type `gibberish` inside one of those functions you should get a PHP error.

Comment: Yea I get `ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in Drupal\Core\Extension\Extension->load() (line 23 of modules/custom/lrg_property_display/lrg_property_display.module).`

Comment: Recreated a new module, uninstalled old one. Same situation, will revisit tomorrow morning when I am fresh. Thanks again...