# Render content type display mode in custom module

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm facing the issue with rendering content type in specified display mode *(teaser)* in my custom module. I have a module which stores **NIDs** in session, and when user enters specific page, I want to load those **NIDs** from session, then get specified node's fields from Drupal DB according to these NIDs and print content types on page in my module in template.

Is this possible, or am I aiming the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Are you stuck somewhere? Or you just wanted reasurance that this is possible?

Comment: I'm kinda stuck. I can obtain NIDs from session, because I put them there. And I can also get all node titles (or labels) from DB and display them on page. But I'd like to display more fields in predefined twig template as I usually do in 'node--product--teaser.html.twig' for example. Can you hand me a tutorial or something on how to reach my goal and display these node fields in template?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-for-custom-module you could pass the node object or an array that contains ur fields as a twig variable.

Comment: I've voted for a duplicate because the question title and the beginning of the question wants to render the node as teaser. When you do this according to the answers there you get automatically a node template where you can theme the fields.

Comment: I dont want to render it using views module and teaser display. But I want to create own display more for example table-detail then render this display type in my custom module according node ID.

Comment: You've mentioned teaser, but you can use your own display mode, too.

Comment: yes i know. But is it possible to define own display mode, create template and then use this template in my custom module I am working on?

Comment: You want to place the template file in the module, not the theme? Then you need a hook_theme(), see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/275923/override-a-node-template-suggestion-with-template-in-custom-module